# How to get local notification when app is not open in android?

Tags: android, uilocalnotification

**I want to set local notification when location is change.so how can i active my app in background and check for update location in andorid.in location listner i set my entire logic for getting notification but i do not know why it is not working and also app is not running in background so please help me. i am new in android.**

```
public class GPService extends Service {
NotificationManager nManager;
Notification notification ;
ArrayList<ImgProperties> arr ;
Calendar calender ;
String distance  ;
Location dest_location;
DBhelper dbHelper ;
Context context = this;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

private static void start() {
}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void stop() {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    private void show() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        GPService getService() {
            return GPService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("geodroid", 0);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
                ,Integer.parseInt(settings.getString("GPS", "3"))*1000
               , Integer.parseInt(settings.getString("Dist", "1")), locationListenerGPS);


    }


    public  android.location.Location getCurrentGeoLocation()
    {
        android.location.Location location = null;
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListenerGPS);
            location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(location == null)
        {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListenerGPS);
            location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        return location;
    }





    private final LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            String Cdate = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + 
                        (calender.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" +
                            calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            String Ctime = calender.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" +
                        calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ;

            Location loc = getCurrentGeoLocation();

            nManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            dbHelper = new DBhelper(GPService.this);
            dbHelper.open();

            arr = dbHelper.getAllData();
            if(arr!= null){
            for(ImgProperties ipp : arr){
                String lt = ipp.getLat();
                String lon = ipp.getLng();

                dest_location = new Location("");

                    dest_location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(lt));
                    dest_location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lon));

                    float[] results = new float[3];
                    android.location.Location.distanceBetween(loc.getLatitude(),
                            loc.getLongitude(), dest_location.getLatitude(), dest_location.getLongitude(), results);
                    double ddd = Utilities.metersToMile(results[0]);
                    int dd = (int) Math.ceil(ddd) ;
                    //double dis = loc.distanceTo(dest_location);
                    //distance = String.format("%.2f", dis);
                    //int dd = Integer.parseInt(distance);
                    Log.e("distacce", String.valueOf(dd));
                    Log.e("from date", String.valueOf(ipp.getFrom_date().equals(Cdate)));

                    Log.e("from date", String.valueOf(ipp.getFrom_time().equals(Ctime)));
                    Log.e("from date", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(ipp.getRadius())<=dd));

                    if(ipp.getIs_active().equals("Deactive")){

                        if(ipp.getFrom_date().equals(Cdate)){




                        if(ipp.getFrom_time().equals(Ctime)){

                            Log.e("", "1");
                                String act = "Active";
                                String patt = ipp.getBmp();
                                ImgProperties imgProp = new ImgProperties(act,patt);
                                dbHelper.updateSingle(imgProp);

                            notification =  new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "you click this", 11);

                            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DashPage.class);
                            notificationIntent.putExtra("ms", "you click this");
                            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "you click this", intent);
                            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;



                            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                         //   notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                            nManager.notify(0, notification);
                           // stopSelf();
                        }

                        else if(Integer.parseInt(ipp.getRadius())<=dd){

                            Log.e("", "2");
                             String act = "Active";
                                String patt = ipp.getBmp();
                                ImgProperties imgProp = new ImgProperties(act,patt);
                                dbHelper.updateSingle(imgProp);
                            notification =  new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "you click this", 11);

                            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DashPage.class);
                            notificationIntent.putExtra("ms", "you click this");
                            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "you click this", intent);
                            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


                            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                          //  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                            nManager.notify(1, notification);
                           // stopSelf();
                        }

                }
                else if(ipp.getFrom_time().equals(Ctime))
                {
                    Log.e("", "3");
                        String act = "Active";
                        String patt = ipp.getBmp();
                        ImgProperties imgProp = new ImgProperties(act,patt);
                        dbHelper.updateSingle(imgProp);

                    notification =  new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "you click this", 11);
                    //new Notification(icon, tickerText, when)

                    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DashPage.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("ms", "you click this");
                    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "you click this", intent);
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                  //  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                    nManager.notify(2, notification);
                  //  stopSelf();


                }
                else if(Integer.parseInt(ipp.getRadius())<=dd)
                {
                    Log.e("", "4");
                     String act = "Active";
                     String patt = ipp.getBmp();
                        ImgProperties imgProp = new ImgProperties(act,patt);
                        dbHelper.updateSingle(imgProp);



                        notification =  new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "you click this", 11);

                    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DashPage.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("ms", "you click this");
                    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "you click this", intent);
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                  //  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                    nManager.notify(3, notification);
                    stopSelf();

                }

                    }

            }
        }

        }
    };


                                 @Override
                                public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

                                     GPService.start();
                                    return START_STICKY;
                                }



                                 @Override
                                 public void onDestroy() {
                                     // Cancel the persistent notification.
                                     //mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
                                        GPService.stop();
                                     // Tell the user we stopped.
                                     Toast.makeText(this, "geodroid service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }
```

Comment: Show us your efforts. What have you tried?

Comment: Divide your problem into smaller chunks. First just get a Toast to show when your location is changed. If you can't solve that smaller problem, divide it even further. And please do not use bold for your initial text, take the time to format your code, delete the empty lines, delete the unused code, delete the not yet supported code, delete DBHelper, and delete all the extraneous lines of code that you just copied from some place and that you do not understand. The more effort you put into understanding and formatting your code/question, the more others will want to help you in return.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to add a Gps Status Listener that will start GPS coordinates polling from available satellites. You should do that before calling to locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...) :

```
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(new GpsStatus.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onGpsStatusChanged(int i) {
                log(getTimeStamp() + ":GSL:onGpsStatusChanged");
                switch (i) {
                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                        log(getTimeStamp() + ":GPS_EVENT_STOPPED");
                        break;
                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                        log(getTimeStamp() + ":GPS_EVENT_STARTED");
                        break;
                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                        log(getTimeStamp() + ":GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS");
                        GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
                        Iterable<GpsSatellite> gpsSatelliteIterable = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
                        Iterator<GpsSatellite> iterator = gpsSatelliteIterable.iterator();
                        int iCurrentSatIndex = 0;
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            GpsSatellite gpsSatellite = iterator.next();
                            log("SAT" + iCurrentSatIndex + ":Signal to Noise Ratio =" + gpsSatellite.getSnr());
                            log("SAT" + iCurrentSatIndex + ":Pseudo Random Number =" + gpsSatellite.getSnr());
                            log("SAT" + iCurrentSatIndex + ":Elevation =" + gpsSatellite.getElevation());
                            log("SAT" + iCurrentSatIndex + ":Azimuth =" + gpsSatellite.getAzimuth());
                            log("SAT" + iCurrentSatIndex + ":hasAlmanac =" + gpsSatellite.hasAlmanac());
                            log("SAT" + iCurrentSatIndex + ":hasEphemeris =" + gpsSatellite.hasEphemeris());
                            log("SAT" + iCurrentSatIndex + ":usedInFix =" + gpsSatellite.usedInFix());
                            iCurrentSatIndex++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                        log(getTimeStamp() + ":GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```